# Wordpress wp_footer not loading

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a theme which i've used before and the wp_footer is loading fine in there. But in the new site the wp_footer is not loading can't find the solution by myself! Is there someone who could help me?

it's in the right place before the `</body>` tag.

```
<footer>
<div class="container">
<div class="footermenu">
<?php 
$footer = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => 'footer',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);
wp_nav_menu($footer);
?>
<img src="http://www.web-lynx.nl/vandervalk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/PBRB_logo-trans-300x41.png" width="300px" height="41px" class="logofooter"/>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<h2><?php _e("ONZE SOCIAL MEDIA","vertaling"); ?></h2>
<div class="one_third">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/PlazaResortBonaire" class="linkicon"><span data-icon="&#xe16b;" class="footersocial"></span></a>
</div>
<div class="one_third">
<a href="https://twitter.com/plazabonaire" class="linkicon"><span data-icon="&#xe16f;" class="footersocial"></span></a>
</div>
<div class="one_third">
<a href="http://instagram.com/plazaresortbonaire" class="linkicon"><span data-icon="&#xe16c;" class="footersocial"></span></a>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br>
Copyright &copy; Van der Valk
</div>
</footer><!-- footer  -->


</div><!-- site-wrapper -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.googlemaps').click(function(){
if(jQuery('.gmap').css('display') == 'none'){
jQuery('.gmap').slideDown();
}else{
jQuery('.gmap').slideUp();
}
});
jQuery('.firstphone').click(function(){
jQuery('.otherphonenumbers').slideDown();
});
</script>
<script>
/*!
 * classie v1.0.0
 * class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * MIT license
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true, unused: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
(function( window ){

    var body = document.body,
        mask = document.createElement("div"),

        togglePushLeft = document.querySelector( ".toggle-push-left" ),
        pushMenuLeft = document.querySelector( ".push-menu-left" ),
        activeNav
    ;
    mask.className = "mask";

    /* push menu left */
    togglePushLeft.addEventListener( "click", function(){
        classie.add( body, "pml-open" );
        document.body.appendChild(mask);
        activeNav = "pml-open";
    } );

    /* hide active menu if mask is clicked */
    mask.addEventListener( "click", function(){
        classie.remove( body, activeNav );
        activeNav = "";
        document.body.removeChild(mask);
    } );


})( window );
</script>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Think it has something to do with this bug!

```
wp-content/themes/ParadiseHotel/st-framework/admin/page-builder/page-builder.php:50 - Undefined variable: ajax_nonce
```

this variable is set like this

```
<?php

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# Smooth Theme Framework Version
#-------------------------------------------------------------
function st_framework_version_init(){
    $st_framework_version = '1.0';
    if(get_option('st_framework_version_init') != $st_framework_version){
        update_option('st_framework_version',$st_framework_version);
    }
}
add_action('init','st_framework_version_init',10);


#-------------------------------------------------------------
# Define Admin Path and URL
#-------------------------------------------------------------
define('ST_ADMIN_PATH',dirname(__FILE__));
define('ST_ADMIN_URL',ST_URL.'admin');

define('ST_PAGE_TITLE',ST_THEME_NAME.' Settings Page');   // Theme Option Title
define('ST_MENU_TITLE',ST_THEME_NAME);                   // Theme Option Menu Title
define('ST_PAGE_SLUG','smooththemes');               // Theme Option URL Slug


#-------------------------------------------------------------
# Load the required Framework Files 
#-------------------------------------------------------------

// kiểm tra tính hợp lệ của ajax
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce($current_user->ID);
//check_ajax_referer( $current_user->ID, 'ajax_nonce' );

if(is_admin()){


    add_action( 'wp_ajax_smooththemes_save_option_action', 'smooththemes_save_option_action' );
    function smooththemes_save_option_action() {
        $st_default_lang_code = get_bloginfo('language'); // DO NOT REMOVE
        if(isset($_POST['save']) && $_POST['save']=='Y'){

            $data = array();
            foreach( $_POST as $key => $arr ){
                if(strpos($key, ST_SETTINGS_OPTION)!==false){
                    $k = str_replace(ST_SETTINGS_OPTION.'_', '', $key);
                    $data[$k]= $arr;
                }
            }

            if(st_is_wpml()){
                // ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE
                //  echo var_dump($st_default_lang_code,ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);
                if($st_default_lang_code==ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE || ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='' || strpos($st_default_lang_code,ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE)!==false){
                    // update_option(ST_FRAMEWORK_SETTINGS_OPTION,$_POST[ST_FRAMEWORK_SETTINGS_OPTION]);
                    update_option(ST_SETTINGS_OPTION,$data);
                }
                update_option(ST_SETTINGS_OPTION.'_'.ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE, $data);
                do_action('st_save_options',$data);

            }else{

                echo ST_SETTINGS_OPTION;

                update_option(ST_SETTINGS_OPTION,$data);
                do_action('st_save_options', $data );
            }


            flush_rewrite_rules();
        }
        echo 1;
        die();
    }


    // for media 
    function st_image_attachment_fields_to_edit($form_fields, $post){
            $form_fields["st_custom"]["label"] = '';  
            $form_fields["st_custom"]["input"] = "html";  

            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->ID ,'medium' ); // returns an array

            $form_fields["st_custom"]["html"] = '

            <input type="hidden"  class="st_attach_btn" data-src = "'.$image_attributes[0].'"   post_id ="'.$post->ID.'" >
            ';


            return $form_fields;  
    }

    add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "st_image_attachment_fields_to_edit", null, 99);

    //----------------Show image size in mediabox-------------------
    function st_insert_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
        // get the custom image sizes
        global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
        // if there are none, just return the built-in sizes
        if ( empty( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) )
            return $sizes;

        // add all the custom sizes to the built-in sizes
        foreach ( $_wp_additional_image_sizes as $id => $data ) {
            // take the size ID (e.g., 'my-name'), replace hyphens with spaces,
            // and capitalise the first letter of each word
            if ( !isset($sizes[$id]) )
                $sizes[$id] = ucfirst( str_replace( '-', ' ', $id ) );
        }

        return $sizes;
    }

     add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'st_insert_custom_image_sizes' );



     include(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/editor/editor.php');

    include(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/admin-users.php');
    include(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/admin-functions.php');
    include(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/admin-menu.php');
    include(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/admin-scripts.php');
    include(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/ajax-media.php');
  //  include(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/ajax-slidebar-generator.php');

  //
    if(file_exists(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/page-builder/page-builder.php')){
         include(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/page-builder/page-builder.php');
    }

    if(file_exists(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/review-control/review.php')){
         include(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/review-control/review.php');
    }

    include(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/admin-meta-box.php');
    include(ST_DIR.'/settings/meta-box-settings.php');
    include(ST_ADMIN_PATH.'/admin-post-type.php');


   include(ST_ADMIN_DIR.'admin-customize.php');

    include(ST_ADMIN_DIR.'post-type-meta/event.php');
    include(ST_ADMIN_DIR.'post-type-meta/room.php');
     include(ST_ADMIN_DIR.'post-type-meta/gallery.php');

}
```

Comment: Post some code,otherwise you are asking people to guess.

Comment: Ok but I seriously don't know which code is causing this i'll post my footer.php code

Comment: There's zero way for anyone to help without knowing more information. We can guess at the problem, but to solve it we need information. The theme, at the minimum, and more specifically the code around where you are calling for the footer. Read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer

Comment: Edited my post hope this explains a bit more! Sorry guys for describing this problem to vaguely